# Eigen for c++ calculating wrong eigenvalue

Tags: c++, eigen

So I am using Eigen for C++ in code blocks to calculate eigenvalues for my matrices. The specific part of the code that deals with this is as follows:-

```
EigenSolver<MatrixXd> b(B,false);
cout<<" Eigen values are: \n "<<b.eigenvalues()<<"\n";
```

The problem I have been encountering is is that one of the eigenvalues calculated for my matrix B is nowhere close to the actual eigenvalue I found on calculator.vhex.net.

For example, for the matrix

> 1 0 0 x
>
> 0 1 x 0
>
> 0 x 1 y
>
> x 0 y 1

where x = -1/sqrt(2) and y = -0.5 , the eigenvalues are 0, 0.5, 1.5 and 2.

However, my code calculates them to be -4.25e-016 , 0.5, 1.5 and 2.

I also tried this for a 5x5 matrix which should have had an eigenvalue 4e-06 , but the code calculated it as 1.4413e-017 .

What could be the reason(s) for this? Are they approximations? 
My guess is memory issues and that a double type value of square root of 2 will not exactly equal to the square root of 2, but I am not sure about this.

What could be a possible fix for this?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] to show your exact code. Also, use a debugger to step through your code to see what it is doing. Note that all floating point values are approximations to real numbers. You should also learn about the inherent limitations of floating point representations.

Comment: It will also help if you learn about some of the theory of numerical linear algebra.

Comment: "Nowhere close" - 4.25e-016 is pretty close to 0 from many points of view :)

Comment: 4e-06 and 1.4413e-017 are also close within the limits of floating point precision.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth yeah I mean they are _extremely_ close, but it is vital for me to have an exact value, since I would later be dealing with much larger matrices.

Comment: Getting the exact mathematical result will be unlikely, unless you work with symbolic maths.

Comment: It appears that EigenSolver cannot give you an exact value. In fact, any code which uses floating point values will **never** give an exact value. You cannot represent many rational numbers exactly, let alone irrationals. If you need better precision or exact solutions, you will need to either create or find a different library.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thanks for the advice! 
I could not put up the whole code since it is extremely huge. The matrix B I arrive at is through multiple functions (based on something called symmetric divisive normalization if I recall correctly). I had checked the functions multiple times on different codes and the matrices they yield seem to be fine (apart from the approximations for fractions etc) .

Comment: I am not asking for the whole code. Please take a few minutes to read the link I gave in my first comment. Specifically, in the context of your question, the source of the matrix B does not matter. You can give a matrix that is derived much more simply, or even hard-coded, as long as you are careful about not losing precision. The important thing is that you need to provide enough code that anyone can copy and paste it then run it and get the same results you are asking about.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yeah now I got you. I did hard code it out though, but still got a _close_ value to 0, not exactly 0. But I understood the issue now, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finding eigenvalues can be difficult when the matrix is near singular, which is indicated with a 0 eigenvalue. You should not expect an exact eigenvalue of 0 ever from a numerical solution, since it will only be good up to some numerical approximation which starts failing near that point.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to what @drglove said, for symmetric (or selfadjoint) Eigenvalue problems you should use the [`SelfAdjointEigenSolver`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SelfAdjointEigenSolver.html):

```
SelfAdjointEigenSolver<MatrixXd> b(B,EigenvaluesOnly);
```

This gives of course still only a numerical solution, so you will still get solutions with a limited precision.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on which eigenvalue decomposition technique is being used. More information you can find here: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__Eigenvalues__Module.html

This is how it is done for [selfadjoint matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix)

```
std::vector<std::tuple<float, Eigen::VectorXf>> eigen_vectors_and_values; 
Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXf> eigensolver(covariance_matrix);
if (eigensolver.info() != Eigen::Success) {
    return;
}
Eigen::VectorXf eigen_values = eigensolver.eigenvalues();
Eigen::MatrixXf eigen_vectors = eigensolver.eigenvectors();

std::cout<< "eigen_vectors" << eigen_vectors << std::endl;
std::cout<< "eigen_values" << eigen_values << std::endl;
```

For general matrices

```
Eigen::EigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXf> eigensolver;
eigensolver.compute(covariance_matrix);
Eigen::VectorXf eigen_values = eigensolver.eigenvalues().real();
Eigen::MatrixXf eigen_vectors = eigensolver.eigenvectors().real();

std::cout<< "eigen_vectors" << eigen_vectors.real() << std::endl;
std::cout<< "eigen_values" << eigen_values.real() << std::endl;
```

Here **covariance_matrix** is the matrix in which eigenvalues and eigenvectors are to be calculated.